# SQL Server Management Studio 2012 Unable to Attach master database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

[image]

This error occur after selected the master.mdf file but the file does not in use.How to attach the database file using query or Sql server management studio 2012.

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------

CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 32(The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.) while attempting to open or create the physical file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5123)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=11.00.2100&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=5123&LinkId=20476
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Your master database is certainly in use. What are you trying to do? You can't replace the master database by attaching it. This is a crucial system database and SQL Server won't start up without it

Comment: i tried but not working @Sami

Comment: Oh, it's master db, it's already attached

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your server is running your `master` database is online and in use by server.

What you tried to do just has no sense at all: why on the earth would one attach `master` database while it's already attached?

Comment: i want database  view in object browser what can i do?

Comment: @PrasannaKumarJ - Expand system databases - you will see it there

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Open your Microsoft SQL Server and right click on Database and Click on Attach.

Step 2: It will open the dialog, for adding a file click on 'Add' Button

Step 3:

Locate your .MDF file from your Drive, 
select the file and click on Ok button.

Remember the Default Path is  c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA
but I am going to place the .mdf file in a different path and try to attach the file.

Step 4: It will display Data file (EMP.mdf) and Log file (EMP.ldf) shown as per below screen.
Click on Ok.

Step 5:

That's it; it will Create a EMP database with data, you can check your MS SQL Object Explorer -> database and it will show the database attached, here it is EMP database.

Hope you liked this article about  how to attach your .MDF and .LDF file in MS SQL Server.

Comment: Check the DB name. don't use the same name which already exists in DB

Comment: No i cant select .mdf file,when i select master.mdf file error will occurs.

Comment: why you are selecting master.mdf file. its default file of SQL